# How do I imitate this low quality camcorder effect?

Tags: photography

I really cant explain but theres a 2000s digital camcorder vibe in the photo and ive been trying to figure out how to be able to imitate it maybe at least in photoshop? wouldnt wanna buy a camcorder :(

Comment: It's not a very appropriate image for the site, I feel.

Comment: Please find a more appropriate picture and let us know what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call that a camcorder effect. It's basically a photo which has had the shadows boosted, and the colours are a bit washed out.

The results and adjustments you could make would very much depend on the original photo, which we can't see.

Anyway, you can do stuff like this in Photoshop using Adobe Camera RAW filter on a Smart Object, and make adjustments to the colour temperature, pull up the shadows, and perhaps lower the vibrance, etc.

Example

[image]

Comment: What's camcorder effect if I may ask?

Comment: @Vikas - not sure if you have access to the removed photo, but it's what the OP is calling a camcorder effect. I don't think it looks anything like a camcorder IMHO. A camcorder was a kind of video camera you could put a VHS tape in.

Comment: I saw the original image. I mean I wanted to know how actually this *camcorder* effect looks like. anyway thanks

Comment: @Vikas find someone with some old VHS home videos, and watch them. IMHO most good camcorders were fine and didn't do anything weird like this. They were generally just low resolution, nothing like HD video of today. That's the only real difference.

Comment: @vikas some VHS camcorder footage here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBOY2Lv9EQM

Comment: @Vikas - the main problems with camcorders were kind of fuzzy low res images (effectively around 320 x 240), poor dynamic range, focus was always a bit precarious. I still own a JVC VHS-c camcorder like the one Marty McFly used in the first Back to the Future movie. I saved the money from my first couple of pay packets to buy it I think some time in the late 1980's. Ah, those were the days.

Comment: Yeah i can see it's just low quality camera.